# Differences between "schaden", "schädigen" and "beschädigen"

Tags: difference, grammaticality, verb-usage, verb-choice

I am wondering about the difference between the verbs schaden, schädigen and beschädigen. In which conditions would we use these verbs? Below I have some examples. I don't know whether they are true.

- Rauchen schadet dir.
- Rauchen beschädigt dich.

---

- Das schadet der Natur.
- Das beschädigt die Natur.

---

- Sein Verhalten schadet unserer Freundschaft.
- Sein Verhalten beschädigt unsere Freundschaft.

Comment: Did you do any research about finding concrete examples, and can ypu tell what you don't understand about the differences specifically?

Comment: Now that you added examples: what do you understand? where do you get lost? Where do you think your understanding seems odd?

Comment: Voting reopen because the question cannot be simply answered by a dictionary, even though showing no explicit research effort in OP, which may have still taken place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> schaden = schädlich, nachteilig sein, eine Beeinträchtigung, einen
>   Nachteil, Verlust darstellen; Schaden zufügen ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schaden))

"Schaden" is the most general one and it means to have a disadvantage or negative effect. It can be used for objects and persons.

> schädigen = **bei jemandem/etwas** einen Schaden hervorrufen ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schaedigen))

"Schädigen" is often used if its not a physical damage (scatching the object/person), but more a general damage to a state or situation, e.g. "jemanden finanziell schädigen" (=ruining oneone financially)  or "jemandes Ruf schädigen" (=ruining a reputation)

> beschädigen = Schaden an **etwas** verursachen; schadhaft machen
>   ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beschaedigen))

You can only "beschädigen"  something not somebody, e.g. "fremdes Eigentum beschädigen" (=damage someones posession)

---

In regard of your examples:

> Rauchen schadet dir.

Yes, that's correct.

> Rauchen beschädigt dich.

No, you wouldn't say that as "beschädigen" refers to objects.

> Das schadet der Natur.

Yes, that's correct.

> Das beschädigt die
>      Natur.

Reading this sentence, I wonder "who does it damage nature". As the damage is less specific I would say "Das schadet der Natur".

> Sein Verhalten schadet unserer Freundschaft.

Yes, that's correct.

> Sein Verhalten beschädigt unsere Freundschaft.

Yes, that's correct. However, as a native , I prefer schadet (I can't give an explanation why).

Comment: A grammatic derivation instead of intuitive judgement from usage would be worthwhile, whether v. *schaden* was a backformation from the noun to explain a "most general" meaning, or an inherited verb form from the verbal root, with an extended *-ig* form for a narrower sense. That is, I wondered before whether *-ig* implied continuity, persistence, recurrence (after *ständig*). Also cp *schädlich*, not \**schädig*?!

Comment: Also, I tend to disagree with your last remark. Cp *Schwerbeschädigter* "(severly) disabled person", vs *behindert* "handicapped, disabled; hindered"

Comment: @vectory, someone can be "Schwerbeschädigt", but you cannot say: "Ich beschädigte ihn schwer." I would say, the legal term "Schwerbeschädigter" refers to to the person's body, not the person.

Comment: Feel  free to write an answer about the grammatic derivation or ask a new question. I just answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO *beschädigen* can only be used, when material things are damaged - not umbrella terms like as nature, environment, universe ... but tangible/palpable, concrete/explicit, quasi manageable/handy parts of it: a tree, a stone ... the moon - if sth. or so. is big enough to damage it ;-)

For immaterial things or persons, animals, some umbrella terms etc. you can use *schädigen* or *schaden* in the majority of cases (except common figures of speech, f.i. in juristic phrases: *Der Angeklagte hat ihn geschädigt.* --> *der Geschädigte*, never *der Geschadete*). So I think, it's not correct to say *Sein Verhalten beschädigt unsere Freundschaft*, only *schadet unserer Freundschaft* or *schädigt unsere Freundschaft*.

Comment: So you deny that the phrase "Das beschädigt die Natur" is valid because  the speaker cannot have in mind some specific area with trees and animals? Maybe I'm to "language-lazy", I did find both versions valid.

Comment: Yes, I do. *Natur* describes everything, which is not created by humans (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natur), incl. universe, reality, character of r. and the essence of things - too extensive. I never read or heard: *Natur beschädigt* - it's definitely unusual.
Maybe we could say, it's a philosophical question. But similar to inmaterial worthes like friendship you shouldn't use *Natur beschädigen*, much better: *schädigen* or *schaden*. ... - if you search in in a well-known searching-engine "Natur beschädigen"=764 results - and suggests: "Natur schädigen"=7290x, "Natur schaden"=40900x

Comment: Please also check out *Umwelt* at https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Umwelt - beyond *Bedeutungen 2a, Beispiele: der Umwelt schaden*. - or compare with substantives: *Umweltschaden* vs. *Umweltbeschädigung*, *die in der Natur angerichteten Schäden* ... ok, that limps: *Naturschaden/Naturbeschädigung* don't exist in German ... but sometimes it's helpful to compare existing composite substantives to find out, which verb is correct.